# Does including an estimated parameter from one model in another model necessarily correlate their errors?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, joint-distribution, instrumental-variables

Suppose you fit a hierarchical model with varying intercepts $\alpha_i$:
$$y_{it} \sim N(\alpha_i + \beta x_{it}, \sigma_{it})\\
\alpha_i \sim N(0,\sigma_i)$$

You're then interested in including the intercepts as a predictor in another model, perhaps with all of this being done in single joint model:
$$z_{i} \sim N(\nu + \phi \alpha_i, \psi_i)$$

By including $\alpha_i$ in the model for $z_i$, is $\sigma_{it}$ necessarily correlated with $\psi_i$?

Comment: You write $\alpha_i$ and $\sigma_i$, but don't you mean $\alpha_t$ and $\sigma_t$, which are the model parameters to be fit during the first regression of $y$ on $x_t$? In this case $\alpha_t$ is connected to $\sigma_t$ since $\alpha_t \sim N(\hat{\alpha_t},\hat{\sigma_t}^2/n_t)$, where $n_t$ is the number of points collected at time $t$. There are plenty of other interpretations, too, but $\alpha_i$ suggests it is a measured data point like $y_i$ and $x_{it}$. I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: @PeterLeopold The indexing of the intercepts $a_i$ indicates an intercept is estimated for every $i \in N$, where the outcome vector $y_{it}$ is of size $N \times T$. For example, we might have collected data on the same N persons T different times. The person-specific intercept across time is $a_i$. Possible to use some different notation such as $\sigma_y$ and $\sigma_{\alpha}$, but the key is that the parameters vary across the indices and that notation is inconsistent.